# Best way to check if listview is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Believe it or not I searched on google but I was not able to find how to see if a listview is empty. I want to hide some controls if so. I tried lv.items.count but it always returns 0. Whether or not the control is empty.

Comment: Is it returning 0 even when the list has items? Odd...

Comment: why not check the datasource before it fills the listview to see if its empty or not.... that should be a pretty definitive answer. Something like dt.rows.count

Comment: Items.Count shows the correct value, more info about when you are getting items count will help

Comment: How do you add items to the ListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Icarus is right about the order of binding mattering, but I'd like to point out that `lv.Items.Any()` is a more efficient way of seeing if there are any items to display.  No sense in counting the whole list if you just want to know if at least 1 thing is in it.

Comment: nice I didn't know this method

Answer (score 5):

`lv.Items.Count` would return 0 only if you check **before** you bind the data. If you check **after** you bind the data, it returns the number of rows.

Comment: I used it in the Load event of the page the result was always 0. Now I placed it inside the databound of the listiview and it worked